# Select rows that can't be casted

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In a column of my table are stored the number of the house address.

Unfortunately my previous colleagues were not a fan of thinking so they made the column of type `varchar` and did not block input on the software... so now I'm stuck with a bunch of rows where the number of house/apartment is "N.I.", "Not Info", "Unknown", etc. instead of a meaningful number...

I would like to select only the rows that are not numbers... something like `select * from table where CAST(column as int)` throws exception

Comment: In some locations, it is valid to have house numbers that will not convert to numeric, like 1/2 number addresses:  ex. 121 1/2 main st.

Comment: And some will have 33a and 33b or things like that.

Comment: i know... for our propours 33a, 33b and 33 1/2 are the same...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [IsNumeric, IsInt, IsNumber](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/isnumeric-isint-isnumber), you can't use just isnumeric it will return true for - signs and other stuff like that

For example, this returns 1

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC('2d5'),
       ISNUMERIC('+')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from table where ISNumeric(column)=0
```

but it may give false positives .....

Comment: To answer OP question, he would want where IsNumeric(column) = 0

Comment: "I would like to select only the rows that are not numbers" Correct Your answer, please. Its return only numeric.

Comment: isnumeric is not foolproof example  `SELECT ISNUMERIC('2d5')`

Comment: @SQLMenace that's why i wrote "may give false positives", in many cases by virtue of given data it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ISNUMERIC(column + 'e0') = 0
```

Comment: Run this  `SELECT ISNUMERIC('2d5')`

Comment: @SQLMenace, Live and learn. Thanks, i will corrected my answer.

Comment: You can also filter out negative numbers like this:  ISNUMERIC('-' + column + 'e0')

Answer (score -1):

Create a function that that tries the cast and any other logic that you needs then return 0 if the value doesn't meet your requirements if it succeeds return 1.  then use the function in the where clause